# How can I calculate accurate energy loss that occurs in a compound pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, friction, oscillators

I want to find out the energy loss that occurs in a compound pendulum. Is simply using the $(1/2)mv^2$ formula suitable ($(1/2)mv^2$ of after and before)? Or is there a more accurate way?

Comment: Measure the vertical distance (photographically) which the centre of mass traverses

Comment: I too think Farcher's method is better, but how  and where do you measure v

Comment: [A physical pendulum experiment with Lego, Phyphox and Tracker](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6552/ace57d/pdf)

Comment: You could do the experiment with a video camera / smartphone and [Tracker sofware](https://www.compadre.org/osp/items/detail.cfm?ID=7365).